How to project one circle onto another for the purposes of angles?

Two circles are concentric with the same radius. Circle 2 (blue) is tilted relative to the xy plane. They coincide at some nodal axis (dotted line) which is the x axis.
Now we advance to some point A along the blue circle, which makes an angle (theta) in the blue plane. What i want to do is project this down to the xy plane, (so the new point will not necessarily lie on the black circle), and then measure the angle that point makes in the xy plane.
I don't know how to do this. If i could get point A in cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) then it would be really easy to project it to the xy plane by just ignoring the z value, then use simple trig to get the angle. But i can't figure it out because the initial theta angle is in a tilted plane.

You should begin by naming things. So instead of saying "I want to calculate the angle that the point that is the protection of a circle that is tilted by a certain angle..." you can say "I want to calculate $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\theta$".

Starting with the circle parameterization $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,0)$, try rotating it about the vector $(1,0,0)$ by some angle $\phi$ and finding the parameterization for the new circle.

This is a spherical right triangle problem in disguise. To simplify matters, I will restrict to a unit radius. I claim that, if I draw the unit sphere centered at the origin and rotate to bring $A$ to the front, the situation is as shown:

Here $B$ is the point where the black and blue circles intersect, with $a$ and $c$ being the corresponding arcs in these circles. After projecting $A$ vertically onto the $xy$-plane, we project it onto the sphere to get the point $C$. This construction means that the plane formed by $A,C$ and the origin is vertical and thus perpendicular to the $xy$-plane. Hence the angle at $C$ is $90^\circ$, i.e., this is a spherical right triangle.

The problem is then to determine $a$ from knowledge of $c,B,C=90^\circ$. We could use the spherical law of sines or cosines, but since this is a spherical right triangle we can use Napier's rules. Then the three angles of interest $a,B,c$ correspond to adjacent sectors within Napier's pentagon (above), so Napier's mnemonic yields
$$\sin(\pi/2-B)=\tan a\tan(\pi/2-c)\implies \tan a=\cos B\tan c$$
This is equivalent, up to labelling of angles, to the answer found by Yves Daoust by vector methods. As a special case, suppose that the "hypotenuse" $c$ of the spherical right triangle is made very small but $B$ is held fixed. Then $a$ must also be small, so we have $\cos B\approx a/c$. But this is just the result for an planar right triangle---as it should be, since the above amounts to a nearly-planar spherical triangle.
